# problem with background image of Bar Button Item

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `Bar Button Item` and I wanna set a background image for it.
Both the `button` and the background image are set in the `xib file`.

Here how it looks like:
[image]

As you can see the image doesn't covers the whole width of the button.

Now, I tried setting up as background a larger image and here is how the result looks like:

[image: enter image description]

The button gets larger itself and still the image doesn't fits its size.
Anyone any idea of how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works very well in these cases:

```
   UIImage *btnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImg.png"];
    UIImage *btnGreyImg = [btnImg stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [myBtn setBackgroundImage:btnGreyImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Of course, you can write this in one line or two lines, I just wanted to show it clearly...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I made the outlet of the BarButtonItem as backBack and in `viewDidLoad:` method I wrote this code:

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 300);
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(callMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backButton.customView = btnBack;
```

I hope this is helpful in your case.